# Pyramid: Preventing being forced to restart the pserve

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyramid

Although I have set pyramid.reload_templates to true e.g. "**pyramid.reload_templates = true**", each time I modify a view, I have to kill the pserve process and restart it in order to see the changes.

How can I get over this and just refresh the page to get the results?

Thank you

Comment: Does it happen everytime or sometimes?

Comment: Every time. I have a views folder where my views are and a models folder for my models. If I modify a view, it won't come into affect unless I kill the process and fire it again through pserve.

Comment: JFYI, `reload_templates` does only what it says: forces template engines to check template source (files, typically) for changes every time it's requested, and reload it if necessary. It does not apply to logic in views. Useful when you are messing with markup a lot, leaving logic intact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I think you can add the `--reload` flag when starting the webserver. This will watch for any changes on files and reload the server automatically. i.e `/pserve --reload develoment.ini`